# mercurial windows batch file for pulling changes to multiple repositories

Tags: windows, mercurial, batch-file

I am a mercurial user on windows and I am trying to write a batch file to check for incoming changes to a number of repositories stored in a common folder (i.e. there could be 10 or so small mercurial repos under a main folder). I have the following batch file that successfully iterates through the multiple repositories and runs hg incoming. However I can't seem to get it to execute hg -pull -u when a repository is found that has remote changes.

```
   FOR /D /r %%G in (".hg*") DO (
    @echo Processing: %%G
    cd /d %%G\.. 
    hg incoming
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 0 (
        echo Pulling changes from the server
        hg pull -u
    )
    cd..
    )
```

I am pretty sure the problem lies with the If statement. hg incoming doesn't seem to have a return value that can be interpreted by the ERRORLEVEL. Is this the right approach or should I be using python instead?

Comment: I have ended up creating two batch files. One that performs an hg pull and another that performs an hg update. This seems to be the safest solution as the output of the hg pull indicates if a repo needs to be merged or can simply be updated. Thanks all for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit code for `hg incoming` and `hg outgoing` is `1` if there were no incoming/outgoing changesets and `0` otherwise and this means that your test is backwards. (The exit codes have been documented since this question was asked and can now be found in `hg help incoming` and `hg help outgoing`.)

Also, doing both `hg incoming` and `hg pull` does the job twice: you should simply use `hg pull`. The help for `hg incoming` says:

> For remote repository, using `--bundle` avoids downloading the
>   changesets twice if the incoming is followed by a pull.

So you're actually downloading all changesets twice, using twice the bandwidth.

Comment: I was under the impression that hg incoming and outgoing were simply previews of what would be pulled/pushed not actually pulling all the changes sets. If I understand correctly hg incoming grabs the changesets and when finished discards them? If that is the case then simply using hg pull -u would be sufficent.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, 'hg incoming' ought to just quickly fetch the meta data (authors, commit messages, etc) and not the actual data. I'm not sufficiently familiar with that part of the code to say why it's done this way.