# Does anyone have a script to handle multiple hg repositories at once?

Tags: mercurial, repository

I have a project that is combining multiple hg repositories (different components) to build a single application. I'm looking for a cross-platform tool to support performing an operation on multiple repos at the same time (e.g. tag, pull, push, commit etc...) Essentially, I'm looking for the 'repo' script that Google wrote for Android, but for hg instead of git:

http://source.android.com/download/using-repo

I searched on stack overflow and found this:

[mercurial windows batch file for pulling changes to multiple repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908452/mercurial-windows-batch-file-for-pulling-changes-to-multiple-repositories)

But it's still a bit manual and windows only. I know it's not *that* hard to write the script to either pass a command to the repos or try to encapsulate everything, but thought that it might be a common thing so maybe others already have a solution. I suppose one approach would be to port the repo script to hg (find and replace git with hg would probably get pretty far for simple operations).

What do other people do in this situation?

Answer (score 5):

Definitely look at the new (in version 1.3) subrepositories feature in Mercurial.  It lets you have an overarching repository that contains other repositories.  The state of the top level includes a file that specifies the hash of the tip of the sub-repos, so you can effectively specify a single hash node id that encompasses the state of all the subordinate repos.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/subrepos

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely keep an eye on it. Don't think I'll be able to restructure our repos to use an "experimental" feature quite yet, so I'll probably invest the 10 minutes in hacking together a quick script.

Comment: FWIW, subrepos are very standard usage now.

Answer (score 1):

I have been in a similar scenario for the past year, working daily with a project spread over 6 repositories, and being the one responsible for most branching/merging stuff etc.

At some point I found a simple bash-script for checking multiple SVN repo's. I adoptet it to Mercurial and have extended it over time. Right now I can't recall or google the original source of the script, so I unfortunately can't credit the original author (will credit in my script if I find the info later).

My "hgall" script is published on GitHub at https://github.com/JKrag/hgall

It is made for my own use, and thus directly references a few extensions that I have been using, but this can been easily edited out. (or just don't use the commands that call extensions you haven't installed).

The script is documented in the README, including my personal "tweak" of having it (by default) ignore repo's that start with underscore, as I use these as temporary clones to test messy operations (e.g. large merges).

I hope this script is useful to some of you - it has been of great help to me over the last year. Our company has just moved to Git, so I will probably not be making many updates in the near future, but might possibly be porting it to Git some day....

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, Iain Lowe has an extension https://bitbucket.org/ilowe/multirepo/src which can manage multiple repositories.